# UWP Resize UIElement using mouse drag

Tags: c#, uwp

This is the situation:
I have a UIElement with 4 Ellipses in each corner
I want to be able to drag these with mouse/touch and make the Element resize

(Like you would in Word when you add a shape, ...)

This is my current code:

```
private void ResizeElement_PointerPressed(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e) {
   var fe = AssociatedObject as FrameworkElement;
   ElementStartResizing?.Invoke(fe, new EventArgs());

   ResizeEllipse = (Ellipse) sender;

   ResizeEllipse.ManipulationMode = ManipulationModes.TranslateX | ManipulationModes.TranslateY;
   ResizeEllipse.ManipulationDelta += ResizeElement_PointerMoved;
   ResizeEllipse.PointerReleased += ResizeElement_PointerReleased;

   pointerId = (int) e.Pointer.PointerId;
   prevPoint = e.GetCurrentPoint(parent).Position;

   switch (ResizeEllipse.Name) {
      case "TopLeft":
         centerPoint = new Point(fe.RenderSize.Width, fe.RenderSize.Height);
         break;
      case "TopRight":
         centerPoint = new Point(0, fe.RenderSize.Height);
         break;
      case "BottomLeft":
         centerPoint = new Point(fe.RenderSize.Width, 0);
         break;
      case "BottomRight":
         centerPoint = new Point(0, 0);
         break;
   }
}

private void ResizeElement_PointerMoved(object sender, ManipulationDeltaRoutedEventArgs args) {
   var fe = AssociatedObject as FrameworkElement;
   var pos = args.Delta.Translation;

   ResizeElement(centerPoint.X, centerPoint.Y, pos.X, pos.Y);

   ElementResizing?.Invoke(fe, new EventArgs());
}

private void ResizeElement (double centerX, double centerY, double scaleX, double scaleY) {
   var item = AssociatedObject as FrameworkElement;
   var visual = ElementCompositionPreview.GetElementVisual(item);
   var _compositor = ElementCompositionPreview.GetElementVisual(item).Compositor;

   visual.CenterPoint = new Vector3((float) centerX, (float) centerY, 0);

   var scaleOut = _compositor.CreateVector2KeyFrameAnimation();
   scaleOut.InsertKeyFrame(0f, new Vector2(visual.Size.X + (float) scaleX, visual.Size.Y + (float) scaleY));

   visual.StartAnimation("Size", scaleOut);
}
```

The problem is that the composition animation "Size" for some reason doesn't work at all. (On all my projects, only "Scale" and "Opacity" work)

**EDIT**

Additional information:
This is a class, not a Control (no Xaml)

```
public class ResizeBehavior : DependencyObject, IBehavior {

   public DependencyObject AssociatedObject { get; set; }

   public void Attach (DependencyObject associatedObject) {
      if ((associatedObject != AssociatedObject) && !Windows.ApplicationModel.DesignMode.DesignModeEnabled) {
         AssociatedObject = associatedObject;
         if (AssociatedObject is FrameworkElement fe) {
            fe.Loaded += Fe_Loaded;
         }
      }
   }

   [...]
}
```

Comment: Could you provide the code for the XAML? From your code, we can not what is the `AssociatedObject` and  `ElementResizing`.

Comment: `ElementResizing` is a custom event which can be used by the control the class is attached to: `AssociatedObject`

Comment: For what it's worth, you can **only** animate the `Size` of custom-created `Visual`'s. The `Size` property for visuals of `FrameworkElement`'s is read-only and matches the `RenderSize` of the element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may not be the most elegant way, but I found a solution by combining ManipulationDelta and changing height and width:

```
private void ResizeElement (double scaleX, double scaleY) {
   var fe = AssociatedObject as FrameworkElement;
   fe.Width = fe.ActualWidth + scaleX;
   fe.Height = fe.ActualHeight + scaleY;
}
```

I removed the composition API methode and used a plain one instead